# Delete/yank into multiple registers at the same time?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

Is there a way to have `y`/`d`/`c`/`x`/`s` output into multiple registers at the same time - for example, `"a` as well as the system clipboard `"+`? I can do `"aY"+Y` obviously, and with `Y` it's alright (only one extra keystroke), but with `d`/`x` it wouldn't delete the same text, or if I were doing a complex motion like `"ad?hello` <kbd><CR></kbd> I wouldn't want to have to type that all over again. Can I make it so that something like `"a"+Y` does the same?

I'm using Neovim v0.4.4.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I don't see how `"ax"+x` would work, since each `x` would delete a different character of the buffer, no? You can set a register explicitly with `:let @+ = @a` (better is `:call setreg(...)`) and there's a TextYankPost event you can use where you could use to mirror named registers to the clipboard perhaps?

Comment: @filbranden doh! I originally had `Y` instead of `x` but switched because I thought it was simpler, without realising that wouldn't work. I'll change it

Comment: I think you might want to explain *why* you need to yank into multiple registers... Is it a named register + the clipboard register always? Would the trick with copying to the clipboard work?

Comment: I want to make all my deletes go to register `a` by default, if I don't specify a register, and if I do, then go to `a` *and* whichever I specified.

Comment: *"I want to make all my deletes ... go to `a` and whichever I specified."* Yeah, but *why*? I still don't get it... The register rules are quite complex, but in a way something like this already happens (with deletes, in specific line/multi-line deletes.) For example, `"zdd` goes to both `"z` and to numbered register `"1` (and other numbered registers beyond 0 are shifted down one.)

Comment: If this is about clipboard mirroring, then there are typically solutions for that. It seems like you're asking questions about how to solve this in general, while you're not really telling us specifically why you want this feature...

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found some elegant way to do so bu you can create your own way to do so.

## Code

1. First you can create somme key bindings (work on visual mode only).

```
xnoremap <Leader>y y:MultiRegister<Space> 
xnoremap <Leader>d d:MultiRegister<Space> 
xnoremap <Leader>c c:MultiRegister<Space> 
xnoremap <Leader>x x:MultiRegister<Space> 
xnoremap <Leader>s s:MultiRegister
```

2. Secondly you can create your own custom command that will take the register name you gave:

```
command -nargs=+ MultiRegister call CopyToSelectedRegisters('<args>')
```

3. Finally you create a function that copy the selected area to the rest of the given registers:

```
function CopyToSelectedRegisters(SelectedRegisters)
    "Split the given registers by space
    let tab= split(a:SelectedRegisters)
    "for each register
    for register in tab 
        echo "let @".register."= @\""
        "Copy the content of the default register
        execute "let @".register."= @\""
    endfor
endfunction
```

## Usage

1. In visual mode, select the area you want and press `<leader>` followed by y (or d,c,x,s).
2. You will be prompted in the command mode (bellow) with the MultiRegister command followed by a white space.
3. Enter the registers you want (for instance `a b c +`) and press enter.
4. Vim will do the copy to the designated registers (you can check it with :reg).

I hope this will help you

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to mention that your maps have a trailing space, or use `<space>` to avoid that. You may also want to use getreg/setreg or the info functions

Comment: @D.Ben Knoble thank you for your response! That's true, it's better to add a <space> in my maps. Also I didn't know about the getreg function. Normaly I prefer using a notation as close as possible to the commands we can make on the interface, but this will be really useful, thanks